# How to find the secp256k1 api?

Tags: api, secp256k1

I want to use the secp256k1 library https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1 (or, more specifically I want to use the python wrapper https://github.com/electrumsv/electrumsv-secp256k1).

I have a pretty basic question - how do I find the api for secp256k1? I wanted to reimplement generating a public key using the library.

Answer (score 3):

The API for libsecp256k1, including documentation can be found in its `include/` directory, see [this link](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/tree/master/include).

The Python wrapper you link to I have no idea about.